# Why Authorization Endpoint of WSO2 identity server always redirect to 127.0.0.1:9443 even if it is behind a http proxy

Tags: spring, spring-security, wso2, spring-security-oauth2, wso2-identity-server

I write a spring security app which uses WSO2 identity server (ver. 5.7) as oauth2 server. The `application.yaml` file is just as the follows:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          wso2is:
            client-id: <id>
            client-secret: <secret>
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri-template: '{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'
            scope: openid
            client-authentication-method: basic
            client-name: WSO2 ID Provider
            client-alias: wso2is
        provider:
          wso2is:
            authorization-uri: https://<mydomain>/oauth2/authorize
            token-uri: https://<mydomain>/oauth2/token
            user-info-uri: https://<mydomain>/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid
            user-name-attribute: sub
            jwk-set-uri: https://<mydomain>/oauth2/oauth2/jwks
            client-name: wso2is
```

And in the identity server, I add a new service provider and add an `Oauth/OpenID Connect Configuration` under `Inbound Authentication Configuration`, the `Callback Url` of which is set to be `http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/wso2is`.

The identity server itself is behind a http proxy of nginx, and I can log in the admin console using https://. I've also changed both `HostName` and `MgtHostName` to .

The question is when I access the spring security app via `http://localhost:8080`, it is redirected to a url of `https://127.0.0.1:9443/authenticationendpoint/login.do?client_id=xxxxxxx`, and from the log, I find it says `Redirecting to 'https://<mydomain>/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxx`. If I access the url directly, it is actually redirected to the `https://localhost:9443....`.

All the samples in the docs are all demonstrated in local environment, but how can I handle my case please?

Answer (score 0):

Open `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml` file and add the proxy port 443 in https connector as follows.

```
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    port="9443"
    proxyPort="443"
```

There are some additional steps [1] when configuring a proxy server for WSO2 IS if you need to work with the end-user dashboard as well (`<IS_HOST>/dasboard`).

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Setting+Up+Deployment+Pattern+1#SettingUpDeploymentPattern1-ConfiguretheProxyPortinISNodes

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I've changed the configurations mentioned in the guide, but however, the redirect url changed from `https://127.0.0.1:9443/xxx` to `https://127.0.0.1/xxx`, the domain of which is still wrong.

Comment: If you have set the `HostName` in `carbon.xml` correctly and have not customized the `AuthenticationEndpointURL` in the `identity/application-authentication.xml`, this should work fine.

But please make sure you are sending the authorize request correct hostname and port first. Otherwise IS will keep using that hostname for other pages as well.

`https://<your-hostname>/oauth2/authorize?...`

Comment: I can confirm both `HostName` and `MgtHostName` has been set to <mydomain> in `carbon.xml` and `AuthenticationEndpointURL` is `/authenticationendpoint/login.do` in `identity/application-authentication.xml`.  And also, the authorization url is `https://<mydomain>/oauth2/authorize` as it shows in the output messages of console.

Comment: One solution would be, using an absolute URL for the `AuthenticationEndpointURL` in the `identity/application-authentication.xml`. This will make sure to use the hostname you configured in the `carbon.xml` in the URL.

`<AuthenticationEndpointURL>${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}/authenticationendpoint/login.do</AuthenticationEndpointURL>`

Comment: Yes, this finally works for me. So, may I consider it as a bug or a defect of wso2 identity server?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue locally, but it was reproduced only if I send the `oauth2/authorize` request with an invalid hostname. If you are able to confirm that you send the above request with the correct hostname from the browser, you may report this as an issue at https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues